pyside6 QObject::killTimer message when running GUI in separate thread
I want to set up a gui that runs in its own thread. Therefor I create my own class MainWindow as a subclass of QMainWindow and created a function run() that is executed in another thread (see code below).
Now my problem:
When I execute run() in a separate thread and use my own MainWindow as a widget, I always get the debug messages when closing the window:
QObject::killTimer: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread

But when I execute run() in a separate thread and use an empty QMainWindow as a widget, these messages are not prompted.
And when I execute run() in the main thread and not in a separate thread together with my MainWindow-widget, these messages also are not prompted.
So my question is, where does this "timer" comes from? I do not use a timer inside my widget-class!?
from threading import Thread
import logging
from pathlib import Path

from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QSize, QTimer
from PySide6.QtGui import QAction, QCloseEvent, QIcon, QScreen
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QWidget,
    QToolBar,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QLabel,
    QPushButton,
    QSlider
)

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

from modules.control.control import Control, ControlCommand, ControlState, ControlStatus
from modules.machine.machine import Machine, MachineCommand, MachineState, MachineStatus
from modules.laserscanner.laserscanner import Laserscanner, LaserscannerCommand, LaserscannerState, LaserscannerStatus

class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):
    def __init__(self, parent: QWidget = None, width = 5, height = 4, dpi = 150):
        _fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self._axes = _fig.add_subplot()
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(_fig)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, control: Control, machine: Machine, scanner: Laserscanner) -> None:
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        # references
        self._control = control
        self._machine = machine
        self._scanner = scanner
        self._nc_file: Path = Path()

        # title
        self.setWindowTitle('label_title')
        
        # menu
        # actions
        self._action_menu_file_load = QAction(QIcon.fromTheme(QIcon.ThemeIcon.DocumentOpen), 'label_menu_file_load')
        self._action_menu_file_load.triggered.connect(self.dummy_callback)
        self._action_menu_file_exit = QAction(QIcon.fromTheme(QIcon.ThemeIcon.ApplicationExit), 'label_menu_file_exit')
        self._action_menu_file_exit.triggered.connect(self.dummy_callback)

        self._menu = self.menuBar()
        self._menu_file = self._menu.addMenu('&' + 'label_menu_file')
        self._menu_file.addAction(self._action_menu_file_load)
        self._menu_file.addSeparator()
        self._menu_file.addAction(self._action_menu_file_exit)

        # toolbar
        self._toolbar = QToolBar(self)
        self._toolbar.setIconSize(QSize(16,16))
        self._toolbar.setAllowedAreas(Qt.ToolBarArea.TopToolBarArea)
        self._toolbar.setMovable(False)
        self._toolbar.setFloatable(False)
        self._toolbar.addAction(self._action_menu_file_load)
        self.addToolBar(self._toolbar)

        # layout & content
        # boxes
        self._box_window = QHBoxLayout()
        self._box_control = QVBoxLayout()
        self._box_control_view = QHBoxLayout()
        self._box_control_view_area = QVBoxLayout()
        self._box_control_view_slider = QVBoxLayout()
        self._box_control_selection = QHBoxLayout()
        self._box_control_machine = QHBoxLayout()
        self._box_status = QVBoxLayout()

        # fill boxes
        # control
        # viewing area
        self._sc = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=150)
        self._sc._axes.plot([0,1,2,3,4], [10,1,20,3,40])
        self._toolbar_sc = NavigationToolbar(self._sc, self)
        self._box_control_view_area.addWidget(self._toolbar_sc)
        self._box_control_view_area.addWidget(self._sc)
        self._label_layer_max = QLabel('10')
        self._label_layer_max.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignHCenter)
        self._slider_layer = QSlider()
        self._label_layer_min = QLabel('0')
        self._label_layer_min.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignHCenter)
        self._box_control_view_slider.addWidget(self._label_layer_max)
        self._box_control_view_slider.addWidget(self._slider_layer)
        self._box_control_view_slider.addWidget(self._label_layer_min)
        self._box_control_view.addLayout(self._box_control_view_area)
        self._box_control_view.addLayout(self._box_control_view_slider)
        # viewing area buttons
        self._button_view_welding = QPushButton('button_welding')
        self._button_view_scan = QPushButton('button_scan')
        self._button_view_defects = QPushButton('button_defects')
        self._button_view_milling = QPushButton('button_milling')
        self._box_control_selection.addWidget(self._button_view_welding)
        self._box_control_selection.addWidget(self._button_view_scan)
        self._box_control_selection.addWidget(self._button_view_defects)
        self._box_control_selection.addWidget(self._button_view_milling)
        # machine
        self._button_machine_start = QPushButton('button_start')
        self._button_machine_pause = QPushButton('button_pause')
        self._button_machine_stop = QPushButton('button_stop')
        self._button_machine_acknowledge = QPushButton('button_acknowledge')
        self._box_control_machine.addWidget(self._button_machine_start)
        self._box_control_machine.addWidget(self._button_machine_pause)
        self._box_control_machine.addWidget(self._button_machine_stop)
        self._box_control_machine.addWidget(self._button_machine_acknowledge)
        # pack boxes
        self._box_control.addLayout(self._box_control_view)
        self._box_control.addLayout(self._box_control_selection)
        self._box_control.addLayout(self._box_control_machine)

        # status
        self._label_status_control = QLabel('label_status')
        self._label_status_control_state = QLabel('unknown')
        self._label_status_control_state.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignHCenter)
        self._label_status_control_state.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(255,0,0); margin:5px; border:1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);')
        self._label_status_machine = QLabel('label_status_machine')
        self._label_status_machine_state = QLabel('unknown')
        self._label_status_machine_state.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignHCenter)
        self._label_status_machine_state.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(255,0,0); margin:5px; border:1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);')
        self._label_status_scanner = QLabel('label_status_scanner')
        self._label_status_scanner_state = QLabel('unknown')
        self._label_status_scanner_state.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignHCenter)
        self._label_status_scanner_state.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(255,0,0); margin:5px; border:1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);')
        self._box_status.addWidget(self._label_status_control)
        self._box_status.addWidget(self._label_status_control_state)
        self._box_status.addWidget(self._label_status_machine)
        self._box_status.addWidget(self._label_status_machine_state)
        self._box_status.addWidget(self._label_status_scanner)
        self._box_status.addWidget(self._label_status_scanner_state)
        self._box_status.addStretch()

        # pack boxes
        self._box_window.addLayout(self._box_control)
        self._box_window.addLayout(self._box_status)

        # central widget        
        self._widget_central = QWidget()
        self._widget_central.setLayout(self._box_window)
        self.setCentralWidget(self._widget_central)
    
    def dummy_callback(self):
        print('dummy callback')

def run() -> None:
    _app = QApplication([])
    # _window = QMainWindow()
    _window = MainWindow(None, None, None)
    _window.show()
    _app.exec()

def main():
    _t_gui = Thread(target=run, name='GUI')
    _t_gui.start()
    _t_gui.join()
    # run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


UI elements and the main loop that manages should always be in the main thread of the process. What are you trying to do?

I want to set up a gui that runs in its own thread, No, you cannot

Qt creates timers internally for various reasons. Attempting to stop and/or destroy timers from another thread is not thread-safe: hence the warnings. This is one of the many reasons why Qt does not support GUI operations of any kind outside the main thread. Running applications in separate threads may seem to work (and Qt won't stop you doing it), but sooner or later something will break and there's really nothing you can do about it. If you want to avoid these issues, use separate processes rather than threads.
